# replace the spaces only in the first column with python

Tags: python

when replacing all spaces with commas in a row using `fileout.write(x) .replace (' '. ',') . but how do I change the spaces only in the first column? I want to break the date and time below into 2 columns separated by commas

```
2017/06/07 10:40:02,Rule VWIRE 02,web browsing
2017/06/07 10:40:02,Rule VWIRE 02,web browsing
2017/06/07 10:40:02,Rule VWIRE 02,web browsing
```

Comment: `replace(' ', ',', max=1)` ??

Comment: @WoodyPride: The third parameter is named `count` in the docs, but it's positional only, so it hardly matters; can't pass it by a meaningful name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Given this is likely CSV, you could just use [the `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to get the columns as elements in a `list` (representing a given row), then work with only the first column
2. If you know for a fact that every column needs this replacement exactly once, you can use [`str.replace`'s optional third parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) to limit replacement

Solving via #2 is trivial:

```
with open(infilename) as inf, open(outfilename, 'w') as outf:
    for line in inf:
        outf.write(line.replace(' ', ',', 1)
```

Approach #1 is only slightly more involved (and likely more correct):

```
import csv
with open(infilename, newline='') as inf, open(outfilename, 'w', newline='') as outf:
    csvout = csv.writer(outf)
    for row in csv.reader(inf):
        # Only splits first whitespace in first column
        csvout.writerow(row[0].split(None, 1) + row[1:])
```

In the latter case, you may want to perform checks to confirm that `row[0].split(None, 1)` actually produced two results, so you don't silently muck up some rows and not others.

Comment: careful when creating `csv`: `open(outfilename, 'w',newline="") as outf` as doc states. Some versions of python (windows) tend to leave an extra blank line after every line.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Thanks for the reminder. I blame the local heatwave for the brain malfunction. :-)

Comment: you're welcome :) note that I never had a problem with the read mode without `newline`

Comment: also: `csvout.writerows(row[0].split(None, 1) + row[1:] for row in csv.reader(inf))` is faster & more compact.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: I believe it can be a problem for read mode, depending on format, if there are newlines embedded in fields, but I'll admit to never personally encountering it. Using `writerows` with a genexpr *is* more succinct (and possibly slightly faster), but it does also makes it a bit more cryptic, which may be a problem for someone who clearly didn't know the `csv` module even existed (and makes it harder to expand the code to check stuff like whether the split happened, handle single row errors, etc.).

Comment: @ShadowRanger thank sir. can you explain to me why there should 1? in (None, 1) + row[1:]) or (' ', ',', 1)

Comment: @baharudinyusuf: The `1` in `split` is the maximum number of splits to perform (can be called as `.split(maxsplit=1)` if you prefer), and similarly, the `1` in `replace` is the maximum number of replacements to perform (sadly, the final optional parameter to `replace` is positional only, so you can improve self-documentation by passing it by keyword).

Comment: @ShadowRanger ohh, if it is 1 then it will replace 1 space into a comma. if it 2 then it will replace 2 spaces into commas. thanks sir

Comment: Yup. Also, typoed my last comment, should have been "...so you *can't* improve self-documentation..."

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
s = '2017/06/07 10:40:02,Rule VWIRE 02,web browsing'
s = s.split(' ')
s[0] += ','
s = ''.join(s)
```

outputs:
2017/06/07,10:40:02,RuleVWIRE02,webbrowsing